# System Center Orchestrator Initialize Data

Tags: windows, system-center

I have created an **Initialize Data** activity that returns a number of strings. There are a few links that spread from this activity, and I would like to control the behavior in such a way that it triggers only when a set of conditions match.

For example:

**Initialize Data**

- Start or Stop -> String
- Time (Minutes) -> Integer
- Type -> String

I have linked this to a **Start Maintenance Mode** and a **Stop Maintenance Mode Activity**.

The links I currently have contain the following behavior:

```
Start or Stop from Initialize Data contains Start -> Run the START MM Activity
Start or Stop from Initialize Data contains Stop -> Run the STOP MM Activity
```

How do I configure it in such a way that allows be to add two conditions? Such as `Start or Stop from Initialize Data contains Start **AND** Type contains Workstation`?

By default I noticed that if you add another condition it creates it with the **OR** switch.

Hope I made it clear, if you have any questions please let me know. Here's an image that describes the above in a graphical manner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCu9Y.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to achieve the above behavior with a Run .NET Script Activity. You apparently can't do it from the built-in link conditions - you'll need to write a script that returns your desired conditions in the form of a variable, and invoke that variable in the LINK properties.